# Random sequence generator with full coverage of interval

Tags: random, sequence

Can somebody suggest me a random (integer) number generation algorithm such that given an interval, it is absolutely guaranteed to cover all the given interval (i.e. o numbers are missing)? No other constraints, e.g. no uniqueness of numbers, no hypotheses on distribution etc...

The idea is the following:

```
myRandom(1, 4)
```

Outputs a sequence like:

```
1, 4, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 3, 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You somehow have to tell your function how many elements you want, say `n`. If that is known (or you have some reasonable default) you can use:

- create sequence from your input values
- select *with replacement* `n - sequence_length` values from your sequence
- concatenate the sequence with the selected values
- shuffle the result

Sample code in R using `4 * (to - from)` as default value for `n`:

```r
myRandom <- function(from, to, n = 4 * (to - from)) {
    values <- seq.int(from, to)
    selection <- sample(values, n - length(values), replace = TRUE)
    values <- c(values, selection)
    sample(values)
}

myRandom(1, 4)
#>  [1] 1 4 3 3 3 4 4 2 3 2 1 2
```

<sup>Created on 2019-07-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>